# Python - Calculate date difference in months

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I need to get the difference between the days in months and days (eg. 3months 20days).

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

date1 = datetime.strptime('2019-06-23', "%Y-%m-%d")
date2 = datetime.strptime('2018-04-17', '%Y-%m-%d')

r = relativedelta.relativedelta(date1, date2)
print(r)
```

This gives me result like **relativedelta(years=+1, months=+2, days=+6)** whereas I need result like **14 months 6 days**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporate a minor modification to get the answer.

```
print(r.years, 'years,', r.months,'months and', r.days, 'days')
```